# Animation transition not running at first click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing an animation for a form with JS and CSS

```js
var userInput = document.getElementById("login-user");

var userLabel = document.getElementById("user-label");

// User Label Functions
function activeUser() {
  userLabel.style.transition = "0.2s";

  userLabel.style.top = "-1.5vw";
}

function deactiveUser() {
  if (userInput.value.length == 0) {
    userLabel.style.top = "0vw";
  }
}
```

```css
#login-user {
  margin-bottom: 3vw;
  width: 80%;
  height: 3vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  border: solid #0057e0 0.1vw;
  background: none;
  color: #ddd;
  text-indent: 0.5vw;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

#user-label {
  color: black;
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 8vw;
  background: #fff;
  margin-right: -2vw;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  cursor: text;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<label for="login-user" onclick="activeUser()" id="user-label">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="user" id="login-user" onfocusout="deactiveUser()" onclick="activeUser()" onfocus="activeUser()">
```

As you can see, when we first run the snippet above, the "username" text just goes above instantlly, without the transition, but when we do the `onfocusout`, it returns smoothly. I want to go smoothly to the top of the input when the code is executed, but I don't understand why it isn't.

Comment: After running the snippet a few times, it is scrolling smooth, in, and out.... Not sure if it "jumped" the first time. I'm using Google Chrome.  May want to click in/out of the field a few times, or try a different browser, to see if that is the issue.  You can [edit] your question to add what browser (and version) you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `#user-label` has to `top` defined in the beginning.
Just added `top: 0;` to your code and it works fine.

```js
var userInput = document.getElementById("login-user");

var userLabel = document.getElementById("user-label");

// User Label Functions
function activeUser() {
  userLabel.style.transition = "0.2s";

  userLabel.style.top = "-1.5vw";
}

function deactiveUser() {
  if (userInput.value.length == 0) {
    userLabel.style.top = "0vw";
  }
}
```

```css
#login-user {
  margin-bottom: 3vw;
  width: 80%;
  height: 3vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  border: solid #0057e0 0.1vw;
  background: none;
  color: #ddd;
  text-indent: 0.5vw;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

#user-label {
  color: black;
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 8vw;
  background: #fff;
  margin-right: -2vw;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  cursor: text;
  transition: 0.2s;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<label for="login-user" onclick="activeUser()" id="user-label">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="user" id="login-user" onfocusout="deactiveUser()" onclick="activeUser()" onfocus="activeUser()">
```